# Custom panel that fills itself with only one child with a padding

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to draw a border that looks exactly like the one a ListView on Windows 10 has. I am doing this because, Fixed3D looks sunken, and FixedSingle looks different from the aforementioned border.

With the Magnifier, I found out that the Windows 10 border is two-pixel wide. So, my idea was create a custom panel that has no borders but draws two-pixel-wide rectangles on its client area, and fit a child, whose border is set to none, inside the rectangles. I have tried the following, but it does not work well with the Designer, nor does it work at all.

What is wrong?

```
class CustomBorder:Panel
{
    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Controls.Count == 2)
        {
            Controls.Remove(e.Control);
            return;
        }

        base.OnControlAdded(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
    {
        var child = levent.AffectedControl;
        if (levent.AffectedProperty == "Bounds")
        {
            FillChild(child);
        }

        base.OnLayout(levent);
    }

    void FillChild(Control child)
    {
        const int padding = 2;
        var childSize = new Size(Bounds.Width - padding * 2, Bounds.Height - padding * 2);

        child.SetBounds(padding, padding, childSize.Width, childSize.Height);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not following your logic, but if you want your custom panel to have a border similar to the ListView, I would suggest that your copy the [CreateParams Property](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListView.cs,9cdcd5b83231f700,references) from the ListView and modify it to create your desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

The description of `AffectedControl` is "Gets the child control affected by the change". But weirdly, it was actually the panel itself. So I changed it like the following.

```
protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
{
    if (levent.AffectedProperty == "Bounds")
    {
        if(HasChildren)
            FillChild(Controls[0]);
    }

    base.OnLayout(levent);
}
```

It works, but there is some flickering when resizing the panel, probably because it is actually two controls, not one as the native border is.